# Evaluating Binary expressions into Hexadecimals by hand

Tags: c++, binary, hex, bit-manipulation

I had to take a quiz on bit's and all questions below are what I got wrong with correct answer displayed. I'm here because I need guidance on how to get these answers.

1. Evaluate each stated binary expression; assume the data type of all values are unsigned char. All answers must be stated as hexadecimal values.

For this question, I got 48. My reasoning behind this was that the starting bit value was 3. `011` and we shift it over to the left 4 places and got my answer (albeit wrong).

```
3 << 4         // Correct Answer is 30
```

Everything below here I had absolutely no clue what I was doing or how these answers were achieved.  The only thing that I can speak of is that each uppercase letter has some assigned bit value to them like `A - 10, B - 11, C - 12, etc.` and that the `&` is sort of like a mask that converts bits from 1's to 0's if both bits column's being compared aren't both 1.

```
0xD7 & 0x3D    // Correct Answer is 15
               // How do you read 0xD7 and 0x3D in bits?

~0xBB          // Correct Answer 44

(3 | 5) << 1   // Correct Answer is 0E
```

I have an exam coming up and I can't arrange a meeting with my teacher with my given time. Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

EDITED: 0xBB | 0x44 , my answer was right. I misread his pen marking.

Comment: `0xBB | 0x44    // Correct Answer is 0` What? That can't be 0. By the way, the windows calculator has a "programmers" mode which can help you with that.

Comment: Um no? `3 << 4` is 48?

Comment: It's what my teacher wrote on my paper.

Comment: 30 in base 16 is 48 in base 10

Comment: I'd spend some time reading this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C but this stuff is very foundational.

Comment: Sounds like you're in urgent need of [an explainer on hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal). Of all the things to be confused about, this is the easiest to fix. No excuse to not know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the expression 0xD7 & 0x3D, first convert to binary.  Remember, each hexadecimal digit is 4 binary digits:

```
11010111 (0xD7)  
00111101 (0x3D
```

The *truth* table for the AND operation (&) is:

```
1 & 1 == 1  
1 & 0 == 0  
0 & 1 == 0  
0 & 0 == 0
```

Applying the rules:

```
1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 (0xD7)  
0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 (0x3D)    
===============  
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 (0x15)
```

Answer (score 0):

A through F in hex have the assigned values 10 through 15 decimal or 1010 through 1111 in binary, it is simply convention (and it doesn't matter if it's uppercase or lowercase).

Four binary digits will always form a single hex digit, so the d7 example becomes 11010111.

You really need to read your text, this material is in there.